# Как убить процесс занимающий порт в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, node.js, pm2

Я тестирую сервер на node который запускается на 3003 порту.
Всё работало нормально, но в какой то момент сервер перестал запускаться ссылаясь на то, что порт занят.
Запуская `lsof -i tcp:3003` получаю:

```
node\x20/ 10955 root   21u  IPv4 2621955553      0t0  TCP localhost:3003 (LISTEN)
```

Хм, видимо при перезагрузке приложение стопнулось, а процесс не убился

Ввожу `sudo kill -9 10955`

Повторяю `lsof -i tcp:3003`

И вижу тот же процесс только `PID` меняется после каждого `kill` как будто стоит какой то автозапуск. pm2 показывает, что все процессы остановлены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, случайно сам на него ответил, но всё же задам его, что бы дать ответ, вдруг кто столкнутся с той же проблемой.

Не знаю в чём дело, но когда я набирал `pm2 status` он показывал, что всё отключено, но я нашел еще одну команду `pm2 ls`.

По идее это тоже самое, но она показала, что процес `server` запущен.

После этого комнда `pm2 status` начала отображать корректные данные. Я остановил сервер стандартной командой `pm2 stop YOURNAMEPROCESS`